# Tcp Client Can not handle large data

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tcp, xamarin.android

Below I have attached the Tcp client code.

Problem : When tcp server send the smaller data then there are no problem. And When tcp server sends large data or package size is too large then there is error and it takes only half message or anything not complete message.And Error is always on Deserialze because package is incomplete so it can't deserialze object. So how to solve this problem?

```
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(lanip, 5555);
NetworkStream netStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
if (netStream.CanWrite)
{
    Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
    netStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You cannot write data to this stream.");
    tcpClient.Close();
    netStream.Close();
    return default(TResponse);
}
if (netStream.CanRead)
{
    byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
    StringBuilder myCompleteMessage = new StringBuilder();
    int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
    var count = 0;
    do
    {
        Console.Write(netStream.DataAvailable);
        Console.Write(count);
        numberOfBytesRead = netStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
        myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat(
          "{0}", 
          Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
        count++;
    }
    while (netStream.DataAvailable);
    Console.WriteLine("You received the following message : " + myCompleteMessage);
    var responseModel = 
      JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(myCompleteMessage.ToString());
    netStream.Close();
    return responseModel;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You cannot read data from this stream.");
    tcpClient.Close();
    netStream.Close();
    return default(TResponse);
}
```

Tcp Server in Python:

````
    def __init__(self,handler):
        print("TCP Server Started!")
        super(TCPListener, self).__init__(name="TCPListenerThread")
        self.messageHandler = handler
        # Create a TCP/IP socket
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        # Bind the socket to the address given on the command line
        self.server_address = ("0.0.0.0", 5555)
        self.sock.bind(self.server_address)
        self.sock.listen(5)
        self.read_list = [self.sock]
        self.keepRunning = True

    # Initialized run Function which will run TCP Server until keppRunning is True.
    def run(self):
        while self.keepRunning:
            
            readableSock, writableSock, erroredSock = select.select(self.read_list, [], [],0.2)
            for sock in readableSock:
                if sock is self.sock:
                    connection, client_address = self.sock.accept()
                    print("connection from" + str(client_address))
                    data = connection.recv(5000)
                    if(data):
                            print("Received from TCP client>> " + data)
                            print(type(data))
                            data=data.strip()
                            print(type(data))
                        
            #print("Loop")
        self.sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        self.sock.close()
        print("TCP Server Stopped!!")```
````

Comment: TCP is an *endless stream of bytes*, not *messages*. If you want messages, it's up to you to implement some form of message framing on top of TCP (or to move to a higher level protocol that implements that for you)

Comment: Yes problem is on client side and server is in python and when i test client in python then it can easily manage all data.

Comment: Actually i am new in c# so can you explain how to solve this error.How to get full message which is sent from server.

Comment: If your Python client is implemented in the same way, then it has the very same fundamental problem pointed out by Damien_The_Unbeliever. It may look like it's working fine for many different reasons, but the code is wrong, and ultimately it will fail at some point (e.g. when network lags). To solve that you need a framing protocol on **both** sides.

Comment: You can replace all of this code with `using var netStream = tcpClient.GetStream();using var reader=new StreamReader(netStream);` and then use eg ReadLine to read text line by line. If the server sends unindented JSON messages per line, you'd be ready to just deserialize the messages

Comment: There are more  problems with this code, including mixing up 7-bit US-ASCII and UTF8 decoding.  Does your Python server really mix the two? Do you explicitly convert some of Python's UTF8 strings to ASCII before sending them?

Comment: I have attached tcpserver code too can you guide according to this?

Comment: Where's the code that *writes* to the socket? What you posted just reads data sent from the client, it doesn't send anything, certainly no JSON strings

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Don't describe how you think the solution will look like, or post random samples you tried to use. Explain the actual requirements. If you want to send JSON data to clients, why not use eg FastAPI? If you want to stream data to the client, why not use gRPC?

Comment: I can't use any framework because i am running Tcp server on device which have very small space.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  Btw i have used StreamReader and now my code is working fine and thanks for giving information.

Comment: You aren't serving anything right now. The Python code isn't sending anything to any client. Writing low-level code doesn't mean your code will be more efficient anyway.

Comment: `my code is working fine` not with the code you posted which doesn't send anything to the client

Comment: I have not posted full code and i have missed that line which sent response back to client.

Comment: You can't use framework, because the device has small space, but you can use C#/.NET, which takes lots of resources on its own. That sounds improbable tbh. Also, do not mindlessly switch to `StreamReader`. Without understanding how the server side works this may lead to other subtle errors. You didn't show us your "send" code, it is likely it won't work in the wild. Btw, if you are writing a real code (not just learning), then you don't have encryption, authentication and other things that are likely to be necessary for any network service to function correctly. Use a framework.

Answer (score 2):

Your `do { ... } while (netStream.DataAvailable);` loop is wrong. How exactly it should be implemented of course depends on the server.

Here's a high level overview of TCP. TCP is a stream of data. So lets say you, as a client, connect to a server. From what you show us is that the server sends JSONs to the client over TCP. With that we have two fundamental problems, both due to the inherent nature of TCP:

1. Packets can be divided and network may lag in between. Say we have a message `{"foo": "bar"}`. But for whatever reason when it travels through the network it gets divided into two messages A `{"foo"` and B `: "bar"}`. This can and does happen. You may think "its ok, my `do` loop will just spin twice and combine the message". But the network is unreliable. What if there is a lag between A and B? Then after reading A your `while (netStream.DataAvailable)` condition will be false (because the B message did not yet arrive at the client) and you end up with a partial A message, which obviously cannot be deserialized.
2. On the other hand, there's a second problem: what if the server sends `{"foo": "bar"}` twice? Or maybe a different second JSON, say `{"x":"y"}`, but very fast, so that the network combines both JSONs into a single packet `{"foo": "bar"}{"x":"y"}`. Now your client reads the entire packet and tries to deserialize it and of course fails.

These two issues occure regardless of what language you use. If your server naively implements sending messages like this, then you are doomed and there's nothing you can do to make it work correctly.

What you really need is a **framing protocol**. You need to somehow signal where one frame ends and the other begins. There are many different ways to do that. One of the simplest is as follows:

1. The server wants to send `{"foo": "bar"}` message.
2. The server calculates its length, in this case it is `14`.
3. The server converts this number to a fixed length format. For example we will assume that messages cannot be longer than 999 characters (3 digit number), and so our `14` becomes `014`. We need a fixed length format so our peer knows how many bytes it should read.
4. The server prepends the length to the message, so we have `014{"foo": "bar"}` and sends this to the client.

Now the client:

1. The client is aware of the protocol. It knows that first 3 bytes are always lengths.
2. The client reads first 3 bytes (in a loop because of potential division of packets). It reads `014`, it interprets those bytes as length L, equal to `14` in our case.
3. The client reads L bytes in a loop. Not while DataAvailable, which isn't really useful due to potential lags. With that, the client finally reads the entire message which it can now deserialize and process.

That's basically how framing protocols work. Of course many optimizatins are possible (e.g. instead of sending length as text, send it as 256-based number in two bytes). Or completely different approaches, e.g. HTTP signals the end of a message by special `\r\t` sequence of characters. Or (as noted by Panagiotis Kanavos in comments) you can utilize `StreamReader` with `ReadLine` if you ensure that your server always serves a single JSON per line (i.e. it appends `\n` at the end of each message, plus properly escapes/removes `\n` inside the message). The `StreamReader` class implements and hides all the nasty details of stream processing for you.

Either way, some changes to the server side are necessary.

Finally, instead of writing your own TCP server and client, I encourage you to use well designed and widely accepted solutions like HTTP clients and servers.

Comment: It's worth noting that all of this code could be replaced with just a StreamReader. If the server sends an unindented JSON record per line, a simple `ReadLine` would be enough

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's a big **if**. Also, since some JSON implementations allow newline inside (pretty print), it is not necessarily safe, unless some additional preprocessing (on the server side) is done.

Comment: A StreamReader that reads a single character at a time is still better and safer than the OP's code. Besides, it looks like the server code doesn't serve anything either

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sure, what OP showed us is... interesting. :) I've updated the answer.